# How to install tensorflow version <= 0.4.0 in 2019

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run an old tensorflow project which was written in `tensorflow 0.4.0`. How is it possible to install `tensorflow 0.4.0` nowadays? I checked the GitHub repository and there is no `0.4.0` tag available.

Also I would like to have a `tensorflow-gpu` version rather than `CPU` only.

Any ideas?

Comment: The earliest I found is `0.5.0` in the official [Tensorflow repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/0.5.0), maybe you can try to [build that version from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) and fix the issues in the code to match that version? Since the versions are pretty close to eachother it shouldn't be too hard to migrate the code.

Comment: well not even the `tf.cond` is available in `0.5.0` so not sure how close they actually are. @Seraf

But yes the `0.5.0` version I have already tried without success.

Comment: Try to find the commit that changes version to 0.4.0 and build that commit?

Comment: It seems the earliest version on github is 0.5.0, they may hosted previous version somewhere else.